# Where can I see "org.xml.sax.driver" system property?

Tags: java, xml

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser reader = (com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser) XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
```

I don't fully understand how the SAXParser class is created. If I go into the `createXMLReader()` source code, there's such property:

```
private static final String property = "org.xml.sax.driver";
```

I looked it up as a package in the JRE System library but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();